# Compare data from two different models with Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm trying to compare two `Django models` with some common fields (`lastname`, `firstname`, ....) in order to apply a process if the answer is "yes" or "no".

I have two models :

- **Person** (which gives the person's identity with lot of fields like `lastname`, `firstname`, `birthday`, ...)
- **BirthCertificate** (it's an act which is filled when a new child is borned with some fields : `firstname`, `lastname`, ...)

With this both models, I have common fields and I would to compare these fields in order to apply two different processes.

My models look like :

```
class Person(models.Model):

    social_number = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, verbose_name='numero social')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=12,choices=TITLE_CHOICES, verbose_name='Civilité')
    young_girl_lastname = models.CharField(max_length=30, verbose_name='Nom de jeune fille', blank=True)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=30, verbose_name='Nom de famille')
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=30, verbose_name='Prénom(s)')
    sex = models.CharField(max_length=8, choices=SEX_CHOICES, verbose_name='Sexe')
    status = models.CharField(max_length=15, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, verbose_name="Statut civil")
    birthday = models.DateField(verbose_name='Date de naissance')
    birthcity = models.CharField(max_length=30, verbose_name='Ville de naissance')
    birthcountry = CountryField(blank_label='Sélectionner un pays', verbose_name='Pays de naissance')
    birthmairie = models.CharField(max_length=30, verbose_name='Mairie de naissance')
    nationality = models.CharField(max_length=30, verbose_name='Nationalité')
    job = models.CharField(max_length=30, verbose_name='Profession')
    adress = models.CharField(max_length=30, verbose_name='Adresse')
    city = models.CharField(max_length=30, verbose_name='Ville')
    zip = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Code Postal')
    country = CountryField(blank_label='Sélectionner un pays', verbose_name='Pays')
    mail = models.CharField(max_length=30, verbose_name='Email', blank=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=20, verbose_name='Téléphone', blank=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    mairie = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=False, verbose_name='Mairie', default=' ')
```

and

```
class BirthCertificate(models.Model):

    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=False, verbose_name='Nom de famille')
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=False, verbose_name='Prénom(s)')
    sex = models.CharField(max_length=8, choices=SEX_CHOICES, verbose_name='Sexe')
    birthday = models.DateField(null=False, verbose_name='Date de naissance')
    birthhour = models.TimeField(null=True, verbose_name='Heure de naissance')
    birthcity = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=False, verbose_name='Ville de naissance')
    birthcountry = CountryField(blank_label='Sélectionner un pays', verbose_name='Pays de naissance')
    fk_parent1 = models.ForeignKey(Person, related_name='ID_Parent1', verbose_name='ID parent1', null=False)
    fk_parent2 = models.ForeignKey(Person, related_name='ID_Parent2', verbose_name='ID parent2', null=False)
    mairie = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=False, verbose_name='Mairie')
    social_number = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, verbose_name='numero social')
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

***First case :***

Assuming that we have the same person between `Person` and `BirthCertificate`. To do that, we compare 4 fields : `lastname`, `firstname`, `birthday`, `birthcity`.

If it's true, I pick up the `BirthCertificate.social_number` and I update my field `Person.social_number` by the previous value.

If it's false, I create a new `social_number` in `Person` and I update `Person.social_number` by the new one.

Typically, the true possibility corresponds to a new baby. Firstly we make a BirthCertificate then we create an IdentityCertificate with more details. The false possibility corresponds to an adult without BirthCertificate.

To the end, the goal is to give a unique social number to each person.

My function looks like this :

```
@login_required
def Identity_Resume(request, id) :

    # Form is validated with an empty `social_number` field
    # I pick up data previously created
    person = get_object_or_404(Person, pk=id)

    blastname = BirthCertificate.objects.all().values("lastname")
    bfirstname = BirthCertificate.objects.all().values("firstname")
    bbirthday = BirthCertificate.objects.all().values("birthday")
    bbirthcity = BirthCertificate.objects.all().values("birthcity")

    if person.lastname == blastname and person.firstname == bfirstname and person.birthday == bbirthday and person.birthcity == bbirthcity :
        # If all fields are identicals, I pick up the `social_number` from the true BirthCertificate id


    else :

        #Homme = 1 / Femme = 2
        sex_number = []
        if person.sex == 'Masculin' :
            sex_number = 1
            print sex_number
        else :
            sex_number = 2
            print sex_number

        #Récupère année de naissance
        birthyear_temp = str(person.birthday.year)
        birthyear_temp2 = str(birthyear_temp.split(" "))
        birthyear = birthyear_temp2[4] + birthyear_temp2[5]

        #Récupère mois de naissance
        birthmonth_temp = person.birthday.month
        if len(str(birthmonth_temp)) == 1 :
            birthmonth = '0' + str(birthmonth_temp)
        else :
            birthmonth = birthmonth_temp

        #Récupère N° Mairie (ici récupère nom mais sera changé en n°)
        birth_mairie = person.birthmairie
        print birth_mairie

        #Génère un nombre aléaloire :
        key_temp = randint(0,999999)
        if len(str(key_temp)) == 1 :
            key = '00000' + str(key_temp)
        elif len(str(key_temp)) == 2 :
            key = '0000' + str(key_temp)
        elif len(str(key_temp)) == 3 :
            key = '000' + str(key_temp)
        elif len(str(key_temp)) == 4 :
            key = '00' + str(key_temp)
        elif len(str(key_temp)) == 5 :
            key = '0' + str(key_temp)
        else :
            key = key_temp
        print key

        social_number = str(sex_number) + ' ' + str(birthyear) + ' ' + str(birthmonth) + ' ' + str(birth_mairie) + ' - ' + str(key) 
        print social_number

        #Mise à jour du champ numéro sécurité social
        person.social_number = social_number
        person.save()

    context = {
                "person" : person,
                "social_number" : social_number,
                "blastname" : blastname,
                "bfirstname" : bfirstname,
                "bbirthday" : bbirthday,
                "bbirthcity" : bbirthcity,
    }

    return render(request, 'identity_resume.html', context)
```

My question is :

**How I can write the comparing part in my code ?**

I apologize for many English mistakes and hopfully being concious.

Thank you

**EDIT :**

```
@login_required
def Identity_Resume(request, id) :

    # Form is validated with an empty `social_number` field
    # I pick up data previously created
    person = get_object_or_404(Person, pk=id)

    social_number = BirthCertificate.objects.filter(firstname=person.firstname, lastname=person.lastname, birthday=person.birthday, birthcity=person.birthcity).values('social_number')
    print social_number

    if social_number.exists() :    
        person.social_number = social_number
        person.save()
```

But I get :

```
<QuerySet [{'social_number': u'2 08 12 STRASBOURG - 039838'}]>
```

and not only :

```
2 08 12 STRASBOURG - 039838
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you cannot do this way since `BirthCertificate.objects.all().values("lastname")` gives a `ValueQuerySet`

So you can do

```
if BirthCertificate.objects.filter(
    firstname=person.firstname, 
    lastname=person.lastname, 
    etc..).exists(): #etc means other fields.
```

**UPDATE**

```
person = get_object_or_404(Person, pk=id)

obj = BirthCertificate.objects.filter(firstname=person.firstname, lastname=person.lastname, birthday=person.birthday, birthcity=person.birthcity)

if obj:
    sc_obj = obj[0] #check if multiple objects are there, means obj[1]
    person.social_number = sc_obj.social_number
    person.save()
```

Comment: Ok I found the same conditions but I didn't know `.exists()` ! If I want to pick up the corresponding `social_number` I tried `print BirthCertificate.objects.get("social_number")` but too many values to unpack

Comment: `.exists` is to check whether that object exists or not. if you need that object `BirthCertificate.objects.filter(
    firstname=person.firstname, 
    lastname=person.lastname, 
    etc..)` is enough. It will get all objects with that conditions.Loop over it will get all instances.

Comment: I edited my question but I don't overcome to pick up just the `social_number` if the previous conditions are all respected

Comment: Please take a look at django queries docs. I updated answer.Also in my answer there is no `.values(...)`.that i see in updated question

Comment: I will take a moment to read one more time django queries docs. Anyway, thank you it seems to work ;)